# Save object with foreign keys in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I use PHP, Laravel 5.2 and MySQL.

During user registration, I need to create a new Patient. But, Patient has user id, contact id and guardian id(foreign keys).

When I try to save() the patient, I get the following exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'patient_id' in
>   'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `patient_id` = 0, `updated_at` =
>   2016-06-07 12:59:35 where `id` = 6)

The problem is that I DO NOT have **patient_id** column. Instead I have **patientId**.

I don't know how to fix this issue. Any help will be appreciated. I can include the migration files if this is important.

**UserController.php**

```
public function postSignUp(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'name' => 'required|max:100',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);


    $guardian = new Guardian();
    $guardian->guardianId = Uuid::generate();;
    $guardian->save();

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->contactId = Uuid::generate();
    $contact->save();

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $user->save();


    $patient = new Patient();
    $patient->patientId = (string)Uuid::generate();
    $patient->user()->save($user);
    $patient->contact()->save($contact);
    $patient->guardian()->save(guardian);



    $patient->save();
    Auth::login($user);

//        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

**Patient.php**

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey='patientId';
    public $incrementing = 'false';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Contact');
    }
    public function guardian()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Guardian');
    }
    public function allergies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PatientToAllergyAlert');
    }
    public function medicalAlerts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PatientToMedicalAlert');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function patient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');
    }
}
```

**Contact.php**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'contactId';
    public $timestamps = true;
    public $incrementing = 'false';

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');
    }
}
```

**Guardian.php**

```
class Guardian extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'guardians';
    protected $primaryKey = 'guardianId';
    public $timestamps = true;
    public $incrementing = 'false';

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not defined relationships correctly. First of all, fill in table fields into $fillable array in Patient, Contact, Guardian classes (just like in User class).

If you want to use hasOne relationship between Patient and User, you're gonna need user_id field on patients table. You can alternatively use belongsTo relationship.

If you want to use custom column names, just specify them in relationship methods:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    // alternatively
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Just go through documentation without skipping paragraphs and you will get going in a few minutes :)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Also, this will not work:

```
$patient = new Patient();
$patient->patientId = (string)Uuid::generate();
$patient->user()->save($user);
```

new Patient() only creates the object, but does not store it in DB, so you will not be able to save relationships. You need to create the object and store it to DB to avoid this problem:

```
$patient = Patient::create(['patientId' => (string)Uuid::generate()]);
$patient->user()->save($user);
...

// or
$patient = new Patient();
$patient->patientId = (string)Uuid::generate();
$patient->save();
$patient->user()->save($user);
...
```

Comment: thanks for your time...i will try to make the changes now

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up your relationship, you can to specify the name of the primary key in the other model. Look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

I'm not sure, but I think you relationships are not defined properly.